# QTip shows at wrong location

Tags: qtip, qtip2

I'm trying to display a qtip in response to the user clicking on a day in fullcalendar.

This works correctly in chrome but firefox and internet explorer the qtip opens in the wrong location.

This can be seen by clicking on different days, sometimes the qtip will open at the wrong location, other times it will open then immediately close.

This behaviour can be observed when not using `$(this).qtip('destroy')` and when `solo: false` is defined.

It seems to happen the first time you click inside a cell, if you then move the mouse within the same cell and click again the qtip displays at the correct position. That cell well then continue to work correctly until the page is refreshed.

---

The full example is available at https://gist.github.com/1467702

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fullcalendar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.qtip.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="calendar"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.qtip.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fullcalendar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                dayClick: dayclick
            });
        });

        function dayclick(date, allday, jsevent) {
            var randomContent = new Date().valueOf().toString();
            $(this).qtip({
                overwrite: true,
                content: {
                    text: randomContent,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Testing',
                        button: 'Close'
                    }
                },
                show: {
                    solo: true,
                    event: 'click',
                    ready: true
                },
                style: {
                    tip: true
                },
                position: {
                    viewport: $(window),
                    target: 'mouse',
                    my: 'bottom center',
                    at: 'top center',
                    adjust: {
                        mouse: false
                    }
                },
                hide: {
                    fixed: true,
                    delay: 300
                },
                events: {
                    hide: function () {
                        $(this).qtip('destroy');
                    }
                }
            }, jsevent);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This wont work in this way. because you don't have the hold of element inside the dayClick Function.

Try in this way, if your requirement suits to you!

```
$(document).ready(function () {

/* Dont care about this code for generating event, Starts Here */
var myEvents = [];
var date = new Date();
var y = date.getFullYear();
var length = 12;

for (var month = 1; month < length; month++) {
    var month = (month <= 9) ? '0' + month : month;
    var startdate = y + '-' + month + '-10';
    var enddate = y + '-0' + month + '-15';
    myEvents.push({
        title: 'event',
        start: startdate,
        //end: enddate,
        description: 'event Of ' + startdate,
        allDay: true
    });
}

/* Dont care about this code for generating event, Ends Here */


$('#myCalendar').fullCalendar({
    events: myEvents,
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        element.qtip({
           show: 'click',
           hide: { when: { event: 'unfocus' } },
           content: event.description
        });
    }
});
```

});

Refer this [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/ramsunvtech/Pzv2h/)

Answer (score -2):

Dear friend you have to add qtip css link then it will work perfectly....

```
<link href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.2.0/jquery.qtip.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```